# Paged ASP.NET repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, repeater

I have a database full of thousands of products and I am querying it to pull back a large set of data each time a different query is ran. I worry that once the project goes live and more and more people start hitting the site, that performance will take a hit. I cant increase power to the server so I would love a solution that could save me hassle down the road. Is there some way of just loading sets in the sql query?

```
select top 20 where xxx
select next 20
```

I'm not sure.

Comment: You'd need to provide more details about your data access strategy. If you are using LINQ, you could always use <DataContext>.Products.Skip(PageNumber * ItemsPerPage).Take(ItemsPerPage) where PageNumber and ItemsPerPage are passed in

Comment: Hi John, sorry, I am using an Entity framework called entity spaces.

Comment: I wouldn't bother optimizing paging - I'd rather seek to implement good search/filter options. Nobody really wants to page through more than 5 pages of results.

Comment: Thanks, I was gonna implement something like Pinterest so when they scroll to the bottom of the page new products appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a new function provided by SQL Server 2005 ROW_NUMBER() you can get result set with row number.This row number can be used for paging on database side.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getcust]
    @PageIndex INT, 
    @PageSize INT,
    @Searchkey VARCHAR(255),
    @TotalRecords int OUTPUT
  AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbcustomer  WHERE cust_firstname= @Searchkey)
BEGIN

  SELECT @TotalRecords =count(*)  FROM tbcustomer WHERE cust_firstname= @Searchkey;

  WITH customer AS ( 
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cust_firstname ASC) AS Row, 
        cust_id, cust_firstname,address,phone 
    FROM tbcustomer WHERE cust_firstname= @searchkey
  )
  SELECT cust_id,cust_firstname,address,phone FROM customer 
  WHERE Row between (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and @PageIndex*@PageSize


END
```